# Resend a received HTTP request - headers already sent

Tags: java, http, ioexception

I have a project that theres a process that sends http requests to webservers that must process long http requests but if one of those servers crashes i need to resend the requests that the web server that crashed was calculating to another of the web servers that is functional.

The problem is that in my solution im getting IOException headers already sent. The code of the project is to big so i build some sample of the process that redirects the request to try and fix this problem and here it is :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class Principal {

static Request request;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException  
    {
   HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8000), 0);
       server.createContext("/f.html", new MyHandler());
       server.setExecutor(null); // creates a default executor
       server.start();
       System.out.println("Server ready");  
}

    public static void resend()
    {
       Thread thread = new MyThread(request.getRequest(), "52.18.4.134");
   thread.start();          
    }

static class MyHandler implements HttpHandler
{

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange t) throws IOException {
        request = new Request("30",t);

        //each request received will be treated by a different thread
         Thread thread = new MyThread(t, "52.31.116.250");
         //Thread thread = new Connection.MyThread(t, "52.50.47.25");
         thread.start();                                
    }

}

static class MyThread extends Thread 
 {
    private String numeroFatorizar;
    String query;
    HttpExchange t;
    private String destinationIP; //IP of the instance to send the request

    public MyThread(HttpExchange t, String destinationIP)
    {
        this.destinationIP = destinationIP;
        this.t = t;
        query = t.getRequestURI().getQuery(); 
        if(query != null) 
        {
            String[] parts = query.split("=");
            numeroFatorizar = parts[1];     
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {   
        //redirects to web servers
        try {
            t.getResponseHeaders().add("Location", "http://"+destinationIP+":8000/f.html/numeroFatorizar?="+numeroFatorizar);
            t.sendResponseHeaders(301,0);
            t.getResponseBody().close();

             resend();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }   
}
}
```

When resend() is called to try to send to a different IP i get the "headers already sent". I need to send the same http request to the second IP because it contains to whom to respond.

The Request code i have there in the beginning is just this:

```
public class Request {
//classe que carateriza um pedido

    private String parameter; //parameter to be factorized
    private HttpExchange request; //contains client request

    public Request(String parameter, HttpExchange request)
    {
        this.parameter = parameter;
        this.request = request;
    }

    public HttpExchange getRequest() {
        return request;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace.

Comment: java.io.IOException: headers already sent                                                      at sun.net.httpserver.ExchangeImpl.sendResponseHeaders(ExchangeImpl.java:204)                                                                                  at sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchangeImpl.sendResponseHeaders(HttpExchangeImpl.java:86)                                                                          at Principal$MyThread.run(Principal.java:76)

Comment: it happens on this line :   t.sendResponseHeaders(301,0);